# Very basic result about intersections and sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x \in A \cap B$. Suppose we have $U \subset A,V \subset B$ such that $ x \in U$ and $x \in V$. So, $x \in U \cap V$. Further, suppose there exists a set $G \subset U \cap V $ so that $x \in G$. Does it follow that

$$ x \in G \subset U \cap V \subset A \cap B $$

??

Comment: Follow? It is more that you are stating it. $U\subset A$ and $V\subset B$ implies $U\cap V\subset A\cap B$. That is the only thing that lacks in your stating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $x \in G \subset U \cap V$ is your assumption, while $U \cap V \subset A \cap B$ is true because $\forall y \in U \cap V$
$$y \in U \Rightarrow y \in A$$
$$y \in V \Rightarrow y \in B$$
hence $y \in A \cap B$

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that
$$x\in G$$
$$G\subset U\cap V$$
and $U \subset A,V \subset B$ implies $ U \cap V \subset A \cap B$.
Nothing new in your last line!